# Why align items center not working?

Tags: html, css

This is my HTML code attempt to create an image grid:

Source at: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_grid_responsive.asp

I want set image display center of screen but align-items or align-self not woking both:

```
<div style="align-items: center;align-content: center;align-self: center;">
  <%foreach $datalist as $row%>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
        <img src="shared/img/<%$row.image_name%>">
        <p><%$row.title%></p>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img src="shared/img/<%$row.image_name%>">
        <p><%$row.title%></p>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img src="shared/img/<%$row.image_name%>">
        <p><%$row.title%></p>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img src="shared/img/<%$row.image_name%>">
        <p><%$row.title%></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  <%/foreach%>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

Why align items center not working?

How can display to center of screen?

Comment: display: flex; ... and you're probably after justify-content: center;... `<div style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First `align` the `content` of warp `div` and not the warp `div`

```
.row{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

or try `align-items` with setting `width`

Comment: Thank you very much, it woking ok.

Comment: haaa... happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
<div>
    <%foreach $datalist as $row%>
    <div class="row" style="style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
        <div class="column">
            <img src="shared/img/<%$row.image_name%>">
            <p><%$row.title%></p>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <img src="shared/img/<%$row.image_name%>">
            <p><%$row.title%></p>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <img src="shared/img/<%$row.image_name%>">
            <p><%$row.title%></p>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <img src="shared/img/<%$row.image_name%>">
            <p><%$row.title%></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <%/foreach%>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items):

> The CSS align-items property defines how the browser distributes space between and around flex items along the cross-axis of their container.

Since the div is not `display: flex`, the `align-items` property does not apply.