# How to center with the property align-item: center?

Tags: css, flexbox

The subject exist on StackOverFlow like here:
[Why align items center not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50042521/why-align-items-center-not-working)

In fact, I have used 2 properties which are `justify-content: center;`  and `align-items: center;` except than, I always have the same problem.

[image]

**EDIT:**

```
.container{
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 35px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: black;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

}
```

Sincerely, I don't understand where is the problem?

```css
body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

p{
  font-size: 13px;
}

.container{
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 35px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: black;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

}

.wrapper{
  flex-grow: 1; 
  position: relative;

}

.first-text{
  padding-top: 15px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: red;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://zupimages.net/up/19/51/vn88.jpg" alt="image" />
        <div class="first-text">Management</div>
        <p class="second-text">
          Assets trust management represents one of the most
          popular operation methods in the world stock markets for
          companies as well as individuals. Among the advantages of
          assets trust management we may mention many
        </p>
      </div>
      
      <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://zupimages.net/up/19/51/9fik.jpg" alt="image" />
        <div class="first-text">Well documented</div>
        <p class="second-text">
          Assets trust management represents one of the most
          popular operation methods in the world stock markets for
          companies as well as individuals. Among the advantages of
          assets trust management we may mention many
        </p>
      </div>
      
       <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://zupimages.net/up/19/51/dwq9.jpg" alt="image" />
        <div class="first-text">Well documented</div>
        <p class="second-text">
          Assets trust management represents one of the most
          popular operation methods in the world stock markets for
          companies as well as individuals. Among the advantages of
          assets trust management we may mention many
        </p>
      </div>
      
    </div>
```

Comment: `align-self: center;` - `align-self` is for flex items, not the flex container; you probably meant to use `align-items`

Comment: It seems your problem is that you have some leftover space on the right if I'm not mistaken. Have you tried to use a width of 100%, get rid of margin: 0 auto and set justify-content to either space-around or space-between?

Comment: Actually  , what you are trying to do? cause  `align-items : center` is used center the items vertically and `justify-content` to center it horizontally, and you should have used 100% of the width , to align the items horizontally properly  cause  the above items also using 100% width

Comment: align-self has no effect on your container anyway as others stated above. delete

Comment: @Yousaf: Sorry, I made a mistake, I modify my code but even with an align-items I still have the same problem

Comment: @Aaron: I tried with `with: 100%` and I deleted `margin: 0 auto` and I added `justify-content: space-between;` and I always the same problem, I don't understand. :-(

Comment: @KALITA: I just want to align correctly my images for now.

Comment: @Yousaf: I want to align correctly my images because there is a space towards the right.

Comment: Something like [this](https://jsbin.com/jobojipozi/1/edit?css,output)?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-antonelli-3n3be?file=/src/styles.css:223-296 @joel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have flexbox feature in wrapper, that's the problem for your case.

```css
body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

p{
  font-size: 13px;
}

.container{
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 35px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: black;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;

}

.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 25%;

}

.first-text{
  padding-top: 15px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: red;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://zupimages.net/up/19/51/vn88.jpg" alt="image" />
        <div class="first-text">Management</div>
        <p class="second-text">
          Assets trust management represents one of the most
          popular operation methods in the world stock markets for
          companies as well as individuals. Among the advantages of
          assets trust management we may mention many
        </p>
      </div>
      
      <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://zupimages.net/up/19/51/9fik.jpg" alt="image" />
        <div class="first-text">Well documented</div>
        <p class="second-text">
          Assets trust management represents one of the most
          popular operation methods in the world stock markets for
          companies as well as individuals. Among the advantages of
          assets trust management we may mention many
        </p>
      </div>
      
       <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://zupimages.net/up/19/51/dwq9.jpg" alt="image" />
        <div class="first-text">Well documented</div>
        <p class="second-text">
          Assets trust management represents one of the most
          popular operation methods in the world stock markets for
          companies as well as individuals. Among the advantages of
          assets trust management we may mention many
        </p>
      </div>
      
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot Evren for your help. My problem is solved.